# $X$ is complete iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|x_n\| < \infty \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges (Carothers, Theorem $7.12$)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, complete-spaces

I have some questions to ask about the **second part of the proof**, i.e. $[\Leftarrow]$ direction:

1. The author says, *"As always, it is enough to find a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges"*. What do they mean by "As always"? Where else is this technique employed and why is it so obvious? Suppose I do find a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ that converges. That **does not** imply that $(x_n)$ converges as well. $\color{blue}{\text{(Resolved).}}$
2. The author asks us to choose a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $$\|x_{n_{k+1}} - x_{n_k}\|< 2^{-k}, \text{ for all }k$$
   What allows us to do this? Given a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$, I know that $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N\in\Bbb N \forall m,n\ge N (\|x_m-x_n\| < \epsilon)$$
   I could put $\epsilon = 2^{-k}$ and find the corresponding $N$, but that doesn't give me a subsequence! $\color{blue}{\text{(Resolved).}}$

*Attached is the proof for reference:*

> [image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For your first question, the author is referring to the well-known fact that if a *Cauchy sequence* has a convergent subsequence, then the Cauchy sequence itself must be convergent.

Comment: Oh, I see, that's what I missed! I was dreaming about non-Cauchy sequences and wondering what's wrong. Thanks so much! That solves 1, and 3. Only 2 remains to be answered.

Comment: To address part 2, note that for any $k$ there exists $n_k$ with the property that $n,m \ge n_k$ implies $\|x_n - x_m\| < 2^{-k}$. Try to figure out why you can assume without loss of generality that $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \cdots$ Once you do, you'll have $\|x_{n_{k+1}} - x_{n_k}\| < 2^{-k}$ for all $k$.

Comment: Yep, for 2) you can construct the sequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ satisfying the property stated by making sure the next index is larger than both the previous index and the threshold!

Comment: @UmbertoP. Please tell me if the following works! Suppose $k_1 < k_2$, hence $2^{-k_1} > 2^{-k_2}$. We know that
$$n,m\ge n_{k_1} \implies \|x_n-x_m\| < 2^{-k_1}$$
$$n,m\ge n_{k_2} \implies \|x_n-x_m\| < 2^{-k_2} < 2^{-k_1}$$
If $n,m\ge n_{k_2}$, then $n,m$ also satisfy the property corresponding to $n,m\ge n_{k_1}$, so it should be safe to assume $n_{k_1} < n_{k_2}$. Is that right? In other words, the assumption that $k_1 < k_2\implies n_{k_1} < n_{k_2}$ doesn't lead to any contradiction or such, but is that enough to tell us that we can safely make this assumption? Thank you.

Comment: @korone Would you have any thoughts to share? @UmbertoP.? It's been a while!

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: How about this: $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. So for large enough $n_1,n_2, |x_{n_2}-x_{n_1}|\lt 1/2$. Similarly, for large enough $n_3$, $|x_{n_3}-x_{n_2}|\lt 1/2^2$ etc. ?

Comment: @Koro Not sure why that would work. Corresponding to $1/2$, I can find some $N_1$ such that $n_1,n_2\ge N_1 \implies |x_{n_2} - x_{n_1}| < 1/2$. Corresponding to $1/4$, I can find some $N_2$ such that $n_3,n_4\ge N_1 \implies |x_{n_3} - x_{n_4}| < 1/4$. WLOG I can assume $n_2>n_1$, but what is to say that $n_2 \ge N_2$? If $n_2 < N_2$, then we cannot possibly put $n_3 = n_2$ and get the second inequality you have written. Do you see my point?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: I think you are right. Please tag me also when you find the answer to this. Thanks.

Comment: One useful way of looking at convergent & non-convergent sequences is that (i) the sequence $(y_n)_n$ converges to $y$ iff for every $r>0$, the set $\{n: \|y-y_n\|\ge r\}$ is finite,... and (ii) $\,(y_n)_n$ does not converge to $y$ iff there exists $r'>0 $ such that $\{n:\|y-y_n\|\ge r'\}$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking $\epsilon = 2^{-k}$ as you suggest, you find that for every $k$, there exists $N_k$ such that for all $n,m \ge N_k$ we have $\|x_n - x_m\| < 2^{-k}$.

Taking $x_{N_k}$ as your subsequence almost works, except that the $N_k$ are not necessarily increasing so it may not actually be a subsequence.  To fix this, we can use Korone's idea of "making sure the next index is larger than both the previous index and the threshold!" Define $n_k$ recursively by $n_0 = N_0$, $n_{k+1} = \max(N_{k+1}, 1+n_{k})$.  Then you can check that the desired property holds for the subsequence $x_{n_k}$, since $n_{k+1} \ge n_k \ge N_k$.

Comment: Very helpful! Hadn't manipulated sequence indices like this before.